# Data Validation - Multiple Scenarios

Tags: excel, validation, formula

All,

I wish to warn users with a pop up if they enter a number with greater than 2 decimal places or if the value they have entered is less the 0.

The Formula I am using is;

=OR(0>N14,N14=ROUND(N14,2))

However as a combination this does not seem to work. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How about `=AND(N14>=0,N14=ROUND(N14,2))`?

Comment: Or maybe `=IF(N14>0;(N14=ROUND(N14;2)))`?

Comment: Thanks both worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

According to OP these *both worked perfectly*:

> `=AND(N14>=0,N14=ROUND(N14,2))`? – Phylogenesis Oct 24 '16 at 10:40
>
> `=IF(N14>0;(N14=ROUND(N14;2)))`? – RCaetano Oct 24 '16 at 11:12